# Launch UWP app from Windows Form - entry point?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-8.1, windows-10-universal

I have two projects in my VS2013 solution:

1. A UWP app that consumes/produces data from/to  local json files

   - this gets sideloaded and works a treat
2. A Windows Form that gets the data from a remote server
           with Web Services

I want a button on my Form to launch the UWP app once the data is fetched. 
(I cannot integrate the two as the webservice authentication libraries won't work with W8.1 )

This method launches only my UWP splash screen however. It doesn't get into the code.

```
 Process.Start("MyUWPApp:");
```

Do I need something like this:

```
 Process.Start("MyUWPApp:MyEntryPoint");
```

Where MyEntryPoint is going to go in the Manifest File on the UWP? I've been trying out all sorts of values for  MyentryPoint in the file like:
App, MainPage.cs, Main() etc.. I'm not sure if this is the way to go.. anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the `OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)` method in your `App.xaml.cs` to handle protocol activation in your UWP app. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) on MSDN where it is explained.

I've implemented it this way and it works perfectly in my app:

```
private async void Initialize(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    // My code copied from original OnLaunched method with some minor changes
}

protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Initialize(args);
}

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Initialize(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code helps for me.Add the code in App.Xaml.cs file.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Initialize(args);
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }
            // Always navigate for a protocol launch
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```